# Doctrine flattening array after selecting multiple entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

When selecting two entities in one query (using a join) Doctrine is returning a flattened array with an element per entity selected. I want an array element per row and inside that element it contains an array of the entities selected in that row.

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb
    ->select('competition')
    ->addSelect('competitor')
    ->from('Entity\Competition', 'competition')
    ->leftJoin('Entity\Competitor', 'competitor', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'competition = competitor.competition')
    ->leftJoin('Entity\Athlete', 'a', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'competitor.athlete = a')
    ->andWhere('co IS NULL')
    ->orWhere('co.athlete = :athleteId')
    ->setParameter('athleteId', $athleteId)

$data = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

exit(var_dump($data));
```

This query returns an array with four elements:

```
[0] = Competition
[1] = Competitor
[2] = Competition
[3] = null
```

The data it returns is correct but I want it in this format:

```
[0] = [
    [competition] = Entity\Competition
    [competitor] = Entity\Competitor
]
[1] = [
    [competition] = Entity\Competition
    [competitor] = null
]
```

How would I get Doctrine to do this?

Comment: When I need that, I use CONCAT with a particular/improbable séparator, and after I do an explode. Ex : `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(annonce_carac.carac_libelle AS CHAR) SEPARATOR "‡") AS carac_libelle`. If you don't wanna do that, you need do a treatment after the query (but wait other response, maybe I'have just not the solution :) )

Comment: So there is no other way? Seems crazy to return a flattened array if you select multiple entities. It should be an array element per row and inside that element is another array which contains each entity selected in that row.